# Which SSD can be Used for the 2nd SSD for Acer Swift 3 OLED (SF314-71-75MW)

Tags: laptop, ssd, hardware-rec, m.2

*I posted this question here because of this post: [Hardware questions and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998)*

---

- I ordered a laptop for which I cannot find official information about compatible SSDs.
- It is an [Acer Swift 3 OLED (SF314-71-75MW)](https://www.acer.com/us-en/laptops/swift/swift-3-oled/pdp/NX.KAVAA.001).
- I found a teardown, see [here](https://laptopmedia.com/highlights/inside-acer-swift-3-oled-sf314-71-disassembly-and-upgrade-options/).
- **Goal:** I want to **add an additional SSD** (2 TB or maybe 4 TB).
- **Problem:** I do not know which **form factor/type** of SSD will **physically fit**. I would also be happy if you can directly recommend a specific SSD (I am located in the US).
- I provide a picture, taken from the teardown mentioned above. Maybe an expert on this site can help me given the available information.

[image]

*(https://laptopmedia.com/highlights/inside-acer-swift-3-oled-sf314-71-disassembly-and-upgrade-options/)*

---

[This review](https://laptopmedia.com/review/acer-swift-3-oled-sf314-71) mentions

> Storage-wise, there are two M.2 PCIe x4 slots, one of which supports
> Gen 4 SSDs.

but I do not understand what that translates to :).

---

FYI, this is a [cross-post](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17733) (the other post is on a beta-community with relatively little traffic AFAIK).

Comment: It supports 2 x M.2 PCIe SSD's  One can only go to Gen 3, the other can go to Gen 4.  If you already have one you'll need to figure out which slot it filled, or just buy Gen 3 and don't worry.  See : [Understanding M.2, SATA, PCIe and NVMe SSDs](https://www.crucial.com/articles/about-ssd/m2-with-pcie-or-sata) See amazon shopping: ['m.2 NVMe ssd'](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=m.2+NVMe+ssd)

Comment: @BlindSpots Thanks. I was concerned about the form factor (e.g. 2280 or 2420 etc.).

Comment: To **downvoter**: I am new here. Without some context, I will not "learn" anything from your downvote.

Comment: I believe that you need to get a 2420 M.2 Gen 3 SSD for the empty slot you have circle in your picture. The SSD to the left of it seems to be a 2480 M.2 SSD.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for taking the time to answer and improve my question.

Comment: I cannot find 2480 or 2420, is there maybe a typo?

Comment: I agree that a *StackHardware* forum would be a great idea. Probably they don't create it because now it seems too late for that and they don't want to filter out and move half of questions to the other eventual site where they would correctly belong.

Comment: He probably meant 2242 and 2280. The gold "ring" seems make it fine for 2280 (which is the most common one), but the silver "ring" (which is probably for 2242) looks very tall in the picture. I don't know if that could change the story. Btw, "gen3" is written above the red circled slot.

Comment: I was probably wrong unless the drive on the left is a 22110 one though. You should really just measure yourself, I guess. The 42/80/110 are lengths in mm (and 22 is the width, hence same for all).

Comment: @TomYan Noted, thanks. I do not have the laptop in my possession yet (in transit).

Comment: Typo on my part. Others might know better. But I believe 2420 is correct. As @TomYan explains the 42/80/110 are the lengths. So just figure out the width and you should be solid.

Answer (score 2):

*(Community Wiki so that I do not get the reputation.)*

- I found a 3rd-party review of the laptop in question, see [here](https://laptopmedia.com/series/acer-swift-3-oled-sf314-71/).
- This review has a table with some specs incl. the M2. slots.
- **Solution:** According to the table, the 2nd M.2 slot is compatible with **"2242 M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4"**.
- I still do not understand why I cannot find this information on the official Acer website.

[image]

Comment: “Community Wiki so that I do not get the reputation.” Well, it’s good you self-solved this, but you also deserve the reputation for digging in to find these details when the manufacturer themselves can’t provide it themselves. Great work!